# How to filter an IEnumerable within another IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

I have this method in a controller that creates a list of students and let's say the Course ID is 5:

```
int courseID = 5;
var students = _context.Students.ToList()
```

Each student has an IEnumerable of Course, so it can have multiple courses. How do you filter them so that you only receive a list of students that are NOT in that course?

So for example something like:

```
var students = _context.Students.ToList().Where(student => student.NoCoursesHave(courseID == 5);
```

but that obviously doesn't work...

I know you can filter really easily when you're just dealing with a single variable like their first name like this:

```
var students = _context.Students.ToList().Where(student => student.FirstName != "Bob");
```

Super easy! But how do you filter for an IEnumerable within another IEnumerable?

Comment: What is in `student`?

Comment: `.Where(student => !student.Courses.Any(course => course.Id == 5))`

Comment: I explained it in the question. It was something I put down originally but I figured was extraneous information.

Comment: Why in the world are you adding `ToList` calls to your code?  It's just actively going out of your way to make the code worse for no benefit.

Comment: Funny enough, my comment got 4 upvotes, but as soon as I added it as an answer, instant downvote

Comment: I am removing asp.net from this question.  I see nothing about this question that relates to the technology.  Please specify your context.  Entity Framework?

Comment: @Rafalon The only real issue I saw in your answer was that you didn't capitalize `Courses`.

Comment: well I did no change to my answer and `Courses` is capitalized...

Comment: If you have a list or DBContext of all courses then you can get the ones they don't have by using ```var remaingCourses = allCourses.Except(student.Courses);``` and the ```remainingCourses``` will be the ones they don't have.

Comment: @Rafalon It is in your comment, but not in your answer.

Comment: @juharr my answer is a copy/paste of my comment, at least on my screen `Courses` is capitalized. What *isn't* capitalized is `course => course.Id` but that is on purpose

Comment: @Rafalon Never mind I was looking at the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[...].Where(student => !student.Courses.Any(course => course.Id == 5));
```

should do the trick, assuming `Courses` is the name of the `IEnumerable<Course>` in your `Student` class

`student.Courses.Any(course => course.Id == 5)` will return `true` if there is a course which `Id` equals `5`, else it will return `false`.

---

From comments, using `.ToList()` at the end would be better.

Comment: What is `Courses`?

Comment: `Courses` is supposedly the navigation property to courses linked to the student

Comment: Where did you get that information from?

Comment: *Each student has an IEnumerable of Course*. So I think assuming that a `Courses` property exists is perfectly valid. I think adding Servy's comment about `ToList` to the answer would be valuable too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman My guess is from `student.NoCoursesHave()`. Edit - also what Dirk said

Comment: Well that's just the typical way, same as `_context.Students`, aand yes look at Dirk's comment

Comment: @PatrickHofman edited my answer to show the assumption

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks so much!! Yes the Students model has an IEnumerable property of Courses inside of it that needed to be filtered through and I had no idea how. The ".Any" method did the trick, I've used it a few times when copying some other person's code but never fully understood its actual use

Comment: @Megawatt you're welcome, I added a note on `.Any`